# Configure the background color for prompted text for auto completion in gvim

Tags: vim

How to configure the background for the prompt area for auto-completion (^N^P) in gVim? I tried many highlight option but don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this setting:

```
hi Pmenu        ctermfg=white ctermbg=black gui=NONE guifg=white guibg=black
hi PmenuSel     ctermfg=white ctermbg=blue gui=bold guifg=white guibg=purple
```

Please choose the colors you like.[image]